# How to create an Adjustment Layer in After Effects via scripting?

Tags: after-effects

I know it's possible to create Shape Layers and Solids via scripting, but how do I create an Adjustment Layer?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Every layer can be turned into an Adjustment Layer.
You can simply create a solid layer and then turn it into one like this:

```js
var solid = comp.layers.addSolid([0,0,0], 'LayerName', 1920, 1080, 1, duration);
solid.adjustmentLayer = true
```